# "um weitere praktische Erfahrungen zu sammeln"

Tags: usage, style

Kann man am Ende des folgenden Satzes `um weitere praktische Erfahrungen zu sammeln` sagen? Denn ich bin Berufseinsteiger ohne praktische Erfahrungen.

> Aufgrund meines Interesses an der Systementwicklung möchte ich gerne Ihr Unternehmen unterstützen, um weitere praktische Erfahrungen zu sammeln.

Comment: Grammatisch ist das einwandfrei; inhaltlich sind zwei Begründungen in einem Satz fragwürdig.

Comment: M.E. ist es nicht einwandfrei. "Aufgrund meines Interesses ... und um weitere Erfahrungen zu sammeln". Sind Erfahrungen nicht immer praktisch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kann man durchaus sagen, hört sich aber ein klein wenig steif an. Ich persönlich würde das so formulieren: "Ich habe Interesse an (der?) Systementwicklung und würde gerne in Ihrem Unternehmen mitarbeiten, um praktische Erfahrungen zu sammeln."

Wobei hier Nuancen unklar bleiben, wegen unbekanntem Kontext. So ist "der Systementwicklung" mehr bezogen auf ein ganz konkretes Projekt, das sich aus dem Kontext ergibt. Allgemein würde man das "der" eher weglassen. Und "mitarbeiten" habe ich mal eingefügt, denn "unterstützen" hört sich so an, als würdest du etwas wesentliches ins Unternehmen einbringen.

Und auch das "weitere" habe ich weggelassen, denn du hast ja oben geschrieben, du hättest keine praktischen Erfahrungen. Wenn du "weitere" schreibst implizierst du, dass du schon welche hast.

Hier kann man durchaus noch feintunen, müsste dazu aber den genauen Kontext kennen.